# Local WordPress site on MAMP server won't display all fields created using Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a local WordPress installation using a Windows version of MAMP for the server. I'm also using Advanced Custom Fields to add content, but my home page is only displaying half of the fields as if it can't handle loading more of them. My footer underneath it is loading in just fine, so that tells me there are no php errors or issues with my HTML or CSS, and it doesn't have any ACF field data to display.

I also had this problem on another website I was working on with the same local MAMP setup. Both websites work just fine on the live versions, even if I updated them with my local copy. So I really think it's an issue with MAMP. I can even take a section that isn't loading and switch it with another section higher on the page and it'll load in just fine, but then the section I switched it with will no longer load since it's further down the page.

I've tried increasing the PHP memory limits, but it's still not working.

PHP configurations I've tried:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M    
php_value post_max_size 50M    
php_value max_execution_time 500    
php_value max_input_time 500
php_value max_input_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.get.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.post.max_vars 3000
php_value suhosin.request.max_vars 3000
```

Has anyone run into this issue before where fields stop loading after a certain point?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had the same problem on my Mac so I tried using PHP version 7.1 instead of 7.2 and it works now. Maybe there is some memory limit in 7.2 that is causing the issue.